# BootstrapPackage did not load correctly VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just installed VS 2010 v 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel on 64bit Win7 Ultimate and keep receiving the following error when I try to open a web project.  I have repaired and reinstall but the issue persists.  I am looking for  resolution suggestions.  Thanks

The 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.BootstrapPackage.BootstrapPackage, Microsoft.Data.Design.BootstrapPackager, Version 10.0.0.0.... did not load correctly.

Comment: Did you ever have a beta version installed?

Comment: No i did not.  I posted my resolution on my blog.

Comment: You could post the link you know =) Now I have to navigate all the way to your profile

Comment: ChiliYago's blog post outlines how to carefully reinstall VS2010.

Comment: This issue appeared on my box after I applied VS2010 SP1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was happening to me as well. In my case I installed Visual Studio on my D drive which is not my system drive. After reading a [link found in ChiliYago's blog post](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/511312/microsoft-data-entity-design-bootstrappackage-bootstrappackage-error-when-opening-closing-solution) I found that the root cause was that files were missing from %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE (Which is what the error message says).

In my case, the missing files were installed in C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE and not D:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE. My solution was to copy the missing .dlls from the install directory on the C drive to the install directory on the D drive, and the error stopped happening.

I had previously installed an Express edition of C# and un-installed it before adding Visual Studio 2010, this may have contributed to the problem for me.

Comment: Buddy, this trick really works. I got rid of that BootStrap error, but ADO.NET Entity Model is not visible when I click "ADD - > New Item" from Solution Explorer, even after installing EF.

Comment: Man this was a huge help! ... I had previously installed VS 2010 to a secondary drive and removed it. Later I re-installed to the primary drive and got this error. Copying the files in Common7\IDE worked like a Charm! Thanks!

Comment: i did the exact same thing as AndroidTaco, except that i reinstalled VS2010 on C:\ and deleted  the few copies of folders that were written to G:\.  it seems that simply trashing the folders on G:\ forces the program to see that they are now on C:\.  no more error!

Comment: This worked for me as well, except I had to copy files from C:\Program Files\... to C:\Program Files (x86)\... I guess it was something to do with a 32bit/64bit problem.

Comment: @DaveTrux - do you remember if this was for the .dll's IDE directory AND all the .dll's in it's subdirectories, or just the .dll's in the IDE directory?

Comment: Is there another way to eliminate this issue besides uninstalling/installing VS2010 with SP1 afterwards (both of which are really time-consuming) ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I Installed Entity Framework June 2011 and then uninstalled it.  After this I had this problem.

Nothing found in internet worked and when I was going to format I found in the directory:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\  these 2 files:

Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.BootstrapPackage.pkgdef

Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Package.pkgdef

Here is when VS 2010 is trying to load the library that cannot load.

I have another PC with Entity Framework 4.0, and it doesnt have these files, so I have moved them out to the desktop. Now Visual Studio is loading the project succesfully.

On the other hand, my problem also was that If I choose to hide the error message then Entity Framework 4.0 didn't create the .Designer.cs of the Model. then when I tried to add the Domain Service Class to the project, the context class didnt appear (but yes in another machine with the same project and same database).

Now that I have not the error message everything looks working good.

I hope it helps others because I have had this problem during weeks.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Tried the uninstall and reinstall of Visual Studio 2010… Still that had the damn annoying message about the Missing Assembly.

Looked on the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ Directory which only showed:
 Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DLL

Installed a LOT of Windows Server 2008 files (32 Bit OS) in regards to SQL Server 2008… ADO.Net, etc… STILL didn’t solve the issue! GRRRRRRR!

So I finally fixed the issue by reading between the lines. See the details below on how I resolved this issue…

This points to the MISSING Assembly:
 Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.BootstrapPackage, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/VisualStudio/10.0/Packages/{7A4E8D96-5D5B-4415-9FAB-D6DCC56F47FB}

Renamed Key to:
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/VisualStudio/10.0/Packages/{7A4E8D96-5D5B-4415-9FAB-D6DCC56F47FB}-123

Problem Solved for now in Visual Studio 2010!

Hope this helps someone else resolve this issue!

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to completely remove VS 2010 from my computer using [official utility](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4321) and then reinstall it. Problem disapeared.

Answer (score 0):

1. From tools menu in VS2010 select Import and Export Settings...
2. Select the last option, reset settings.
3. Save them, why not :)
4. Select a canned default, such as Visual C#.
5. Post your differences here, so that you know what to re-enable, and Microsoft people know what needs to be fixed.

Comment: I was not prudent, and did not save what was actually causing the issue.  I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: One setting I had to re-apply right away was to disable auto-indexing of C++ headers: Tools, Options, Text Editor, C/C++, Advanced, Disable Database AutoUpdates = true.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem, i solved it by rapairing it from "**Control Panlel**" clicking "**Change/Remove**" and tan choosing "**Repair**". BTW i'm using Win XP but i think that uninstallers in Visual Studio are the same. So.. Good luck!