# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 will not compile, load/create files, or recognize the iostream?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have been attempting to run Visual Studio 2010 on my laptop (runs Windows 7 Home Premium) and has all updates, yet, to my dismay, VS2010 *still* does not run correctly after continually trying to reinstall and alter permissions.

I literally went into each key on my computer that had a conflict with VS2010 and edited the permissions for hours, but I VS2010 fails to create projects.

If I load a project I have saved and compiled elsewhere, it loads but not without giving me this error:

> The 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.BootstrapPackage.BootstrapPackage,
>   Microsoft.Data.Entitity.Design.BootstrapPackage, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' package did not load
>   correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the
>   installation of another extension.

---

If I attempt to compile after disregarding this fatal error:

> 1>finProjCode.cpp(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
>   'iostream': No such file or directory

---

Furthermore, if I reset the settings for import/export, then select Visual C++ Development Settings, I get the following errors:

> The 'Visual Studio Tools for Office Project Client Package for Excel'
>   package did not load correctly.

Followed by this error:

> The 'Visual Studio Tools for Office Project Client Package for Word'
>   package did not load correctly.

And then this error *again*:

> The 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.BootstrapPackage.BootstrapPackage,
>   Microsoft.Data.Entitity.Design.BootstrapPackage, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' package did not load
>   correctly.

Followed by:

> The
>   'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Package.MicrosoftDataEntityDesignPackage,
>   Microsoft.Data.Entitity.Design.Package, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' package did not load
>   correctly.

---

Yet after all of that, it tells me that the settings were successfully reset to Visual C++ Development Settings...

I am literally going insane from how many times I have reinstalled, manually edited each key's permission on my computer, and fiddled with this program while trying to do a final project for tomorrow, which I have been trying to type up on VS2010 for a few months now, asking for help on multiple sites, etc.

I am hoping I will get the answer(s) I need from here, if any, and I thank any and all who take the time to look and help!

Sincerely,

Justin

Comment: Are you using, or did you have beta 2010 installed?

Comment: http://www.theodells.org/theodells/blog/2010/07/resolving-bootstrappackage-load-error-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: @Robinson I have not had or used the beta 2010 on my laptop at any point in time, though this issue has continued for a while now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BootstrapPackage did not load correctly VS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267877/bootstrappackage-did-not-load-correctly-vs-2010)

Answer (score 0):

1>finProjCode.cpp(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory

From this I can see that either you are missing some files/libraries etc. Have you tried the uninstalling your current vs with a Uninstall application because sometimes windows inbuilt uninstaller will create some problems.

So do the following:
1)Uninstall your current vs
2)Install the express version
3)Tell me if you get the same errors

Comment: = I still have the issuewith the fatal error and iostream when attemting to compile any porgrams.

Comment: All other messages do not come up, though, when runnign express oddly enough.

Comment: This is not the solution as of yet, though, it helped with the other error messages. It still does NOT compile and gives the same fatal error C1083.